# How to create directory and move WAR file using Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

By default, Gradle puts all WAR files that it creates in `build/libs` when I run `gradle build` on a Java project. How do I instruct Gradle to create a directory called `dist` under `build` and put all WAR files in that directory (i.e. `build/dist`)?

Answer (score 3):

I created a new task called `moveWar` that accomplished what I wanted:

```
task moveWar(type: Copy) {
    from 'build/libs'
    into 'build/dist'
}
```

Then I used `build.finalizedBy moveWar` to move the WAR file in `libs` to `dist` after the build is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I found:

```
war.destinationDir = file "$buildDir/dist"
```